# How to detect orientation of ios simulator at launch app?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I saw that too many answers for this question but they almost about ios device, not about ios simulator. I want to detect orientation of iphone simulator. I rotate iphone simulator to landscape but so far all solutions return portrait orientation at launch app. Is this ios simulator's bug? I have no device to test, so i need to test on simulator first but it seems to be not work correct on simulator. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Well I don't see How this could be an iOS bug since you're NOT using iOS from what I understood... I would say it's a simulator bug then... and not a programming question

Comment: sorry if this question is in wrong place, i quite new to ios, i found a few ways to detect orientation, but at launch app they work incorrectly. So i need to confirm that if this is bug of simulator or not! In case it's not bug, how to achieve that! thanks

Comment: It's obviously a trivial bug in an OS used by millions of people. Definitely couldn't be a bug in a somewhat obscure simulator... The best way to test your app would be buying/renting/borrowing a device, I would say... unless you want to write code that was only tested on a simulator...

Comment: a trivial bug but really annoying, there are various devices out there to buy. anyway thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete portrait modes from the 'Supported interface orientations' array in the Info.plist file of your application. I was able to force landscape startup with this.